# BigCommerce API - Order Shipping Address - Form Fields - Badly Structured XML

Tags: xml, bigcommerce, form-fields

When I use the Get Order Shipping Addresses operation of the BigCommerce API, it returns a rather badly structured XML string.

The part that is the problem is the form_fields node. Within this node, there are various entries that contain a name element, and either a value element or a value node with an element called value. It’s this value part that is the problem.

To be correctly structured, I believe it should either be a node with an element or just an element, it shouldn’t be switching between them. Have a look at the one called “Authority to Leave” compared to any of the others and you will see what I mean.

Does anyone know if there’s a way of changing this so that the XML is structured the same for all of the form fields against order shipping addresses?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but - If you prefer JSON, you can just append `.json` to the end of the URL or set your Accept header to `application/json`.

Comment: to be able to see your XML file in one place, you should use any XML tool. I personally use https://xmleditoronline.org/ to beautify XML.  Paste your XML and share the link here, which could be helpful for us about the invalid XML.